# Is there a word for the "Matrix" representing a Tensor?

Tags: matrices, tensors

A Tensor is a multilinear function mapping $k$ Vectors $v \in V$ to a Field $\mathbb{K}$:
$$
T:V^k \rightarrow \mathbb{K}
$$
For a given Basis of $V$, we can take all combinations of the basis vectors and map them using the Tensor. This gives us a sort of grid of numbers in $k$ dimensions. In 2 Dimensions, we get a transformation Matrix. In 1 Dimension, we get a Vector. Is there a word describing the resulting grid in the general case?

Comment: Yes, "array". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

Comment: @SeanEberhard thanks!